# Could AWS EC2 instances ping Client VPN on the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have a scenario where I have multiple Raspberry Pis connected to the Client VPN Endpoint and an EC2 instance on the same VPC. I want to SSH into those Raspberry Pis by using the IP addresses that the VPN provided.

I have a VPC with one subnet where I have one EC2 instance and a Client VPN endpoint on the same VPC. The Client VPN could ping the EC2 instance but the EC2 instance could not ping the Client VPN?
Could AWS EC2 instances ping Client VPN on the same VPC? If so, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a solution where I connected the EC2 to the Client VPN and I was able to communicate with the Raspberry Pis.